# javax.mail.BodyPart getfileName returns null java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to read the filname of bodyPart in .mime.

```
BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                if (bodyPart.getFileName() == null) {
                    continue; // dealing with attachments only
                }
                do something
            }
```

but , I cant read the filename because it is null : bodyPart.getFileName() and bodyPart.getDescription()

Here is the  full MIME structure of the message

```
Delivered-To: recepcion@test.com.co
Received: by 2002:a05:6638:602:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id g2csp7289198jar;
        Wed, 12 Feb 2020 03:27:35 -0800 (PST)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqxVHblFza+DRlwwecFbjw+ZedxuEjpCI5b/uJ7R59Zur4WA4wXcDmPphAbV4S3Zss9J4XGt
X-Received: by 2002:a02:a14f:: with SMTP id m15mr18470835jah.16.1581506854695;
        Wed, 12 Feb 2020 03:27:34 -0800 (PST)
ARC-Seal: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; t=1581506854; cv=pass;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=I7YjoykmA6j/UaYiByibb2R0yeWjZovjReY+25Wz/GfeVgFnhKMSNSdPdn6XXFI3iT
         JMrB7LOXwbS2SrU9eWUKaBWFmBPhEO9m9AGEgxstS3aqIJjIYDiod9dWhIbLt3MUEzrW
         dmOa2aYoeyJTYBLLEAUFh07qBp58BdJeeqiVMzpggAkD7BuRYEOwkpaSWIQjcdWnQ/Uk
         LHtm5sxi7RagDjV0J+c/QFu2xHlTXRaPKmDCoPEZ7u5S+cDr28BBHGdrbd8kMx2z2rcX
         DUYFPRj9VA+wKQX1SGGdLEbcmvnWf4mIStW4EcXgMpxUjyXt/ggMIZeqacT/T6lZ7mK3
         mRYQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=2; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=mime-version:message-id:subject:date:to:from:sender:dkim-signature;
        bh=SuL/1onLqbG0l9DryV1UAK7Q/UGPMxd0j7R1Yfr2v+8=;
        b=s8RW1hxDeaa8Ix9rDYEagQMmCXYYH9aGJYYyz87ADVcRy15ei6cWz7Lhc9X+NkdEaR
         fPGNcHC0pkL4YV0p/tUulkkOMJkqzr+urRx+3spkWpeX29jDqC5wFUDDdcKahKj+GHfa
         tAtpMu+0tnmaeraXkEcfDg1YwHOEz9nryw5SMljiXxUKqMNf/bDRFR2yuCiDjS4XvBzI
         WwtjpioAziQz9PxwUoCTbITuhDFI+2K2U/2YOiA6SV/JpDT6rkc7V9eLjpY9dJINW8eR
         1Bvu7oZFFzF/xYpsXZqeG+VXhK4MRj9zbKb/KpqGsdTaBw6PccDH5W+ZUOMB87OdAv5f
         9YdQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=2; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@orgdann.onmicrosoft.com header.s=selector2-orgdann-onmicrosoft-com header.b=gXDk4axS;
       arc=pass (i=1 spf=pass spfdomain=hotelesdann.com dkim=pass dkdomain=hotelesdann.com dmarc=pass fromdomain=hotelesdann.com);
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of facturacion.electronica@hotelesdann.com designates 40.107.244.61 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=facturacion.electronica@test.com
Return-Path: <facturacion.electronica@test.com>
Received: from NAM12-MW2-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (mail-mw2nam12on2061.outbound.protection.outlook.com. [40.107.244.61])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id t83si5381257ilb.10.2020.02.12.03.27.33
        for <recepcion_fe@test.com.co>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 12 Feb 2020 03:27:34 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of facturacion.electronica@test.com designates 40.107.244.61 as permitted sender) client-ip=40.107.244.61;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@orgdann.onmicrosoft.com header.s=selector2-orgdann-onmicrosoft-com header.b=gXDk4axS;
       arc=pass (i=1 spf=pass spfdomain=hotelesdann.com dkim=pass dkdomain=test.com dmarc=pass fromdomain=test.com);
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of facturacion.electronica@test.com designates 40.107.244.61 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=facturacion.electronica@test.com
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; s=arcselector9901; d=microsoft.com; cv=none;
 b=OEHELy0NTGlfOZ9lxrryHiWk+VIiAQ+RFGobECVX/W+2AP6kiz4ZXrz9PNe3/SBNOdhoHYPK6KpGeHkz/FB3MFsL8ZCcXFTmRnPoP5ZYSyi86QuZzG1LdeD/BKrcniWp+M/vuHfZqIYw02tmeyZ6NQO7FrdZtuMmCBfFeuMazZX8DzpKuw5G9qtwCmDf8e/FzIzzKkGSoMTBwWLAD7jcuEY293ykWjZYiA9YuaXS+sACoDbB4mkDTWbEFfw0L12iiqao+ywR3LruP1eLqDPnOpO2dzrN9yjbnYHkXdpye/uLiqXLI9j24FyXl3lp7TKNN3TK1huvy4qXDP2qZlpu6A==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=microsoft.com;
 s=arcselector9901;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck;
 bh=SuL/1onLqbG0l9DryV1UAK7Q/UGPMxd0j7R1Yfr2v+8=;
 b=Vhr2jLN2qA2vbEib62auiVI8nJvKF7SG+FnZjeTY7+U417Zr16BAH3woudWoNj/pr5MMnY+DZp2Biqx5GJVJ58d1k7PS/IfRc2H5EcyeW1q492D9a/CJZd5lVCgZxPA6AuNDuPU8/7mZaKEkJOUkgAFINHnnrhSmlOvCUQ7ubmJsIux+jB4HiKJFgebL/2KsDYwziDxH4MgdcUufI6+jgJXD0dwtD7qTsjHwMre4PijoKf/8Eg3MtwPjaGZraIyzCgTwaqgQ8t/jn3JPZBUB2XqEGJlA/In6Eq7VIRVSxgyyvQop63PzUAzvoUfylMT95/M51VPLELNJ7w9cQYAtkw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.microsoft.com 1; spf=pass
 smtp.mailfrom=hotelesdann.com; dmarc=pass action=none
 header.from=hotelesdann.com; dkim=pass header.d=hotelesdann.com; arc=none
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
 d=orgdann.onmicrosoft.com; s=selector2-orgdann-onmicrosoft-com;
 h=From:Date:Subject:Message-ID:Content-Type:MIME-Version:X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck;
 bh=SuL/1onLqbG0l9DryV1UAK7Q/UGPMxd0j7R1Yfr2v+8=;
 b=gXDk4axS5wMO9hM0TibKoIt5DIytaUJspGm7BxNn8+fKcrnNxI43Pwjov8HfJydGNqr1+xX6yJ8y9V+amBMcQxLLJsUzmtYkbdFf/25Ye5qASwm40eQP+rFaRVLPOqrb0a4sUBn2pAWH7K6+kZlYnAjg4q4tze+6TDXNMgIHjGI=
Authentication-Results: spf=none (sender IP is )
 smtp.mailfrom=facturacion.electronica@test.com;
Received: from SN6PR01MB4190.prod.exchangelabs.com (52.135.121.96) by
 SN6PR01MB4063.prod.exchangelabs.com (52.135.120.154) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.2707.26; Wed, 12 Feb 2020 11:27:30 +0000
Received: from SN6PR01MB4190.prod.exchangelabs.com
 ([fe80::edc5:67c7:427:fb6b]) by SN6PR01MB4190.prod.exchangelabs.com
 ([fe80::edc5:67c7:427:fb6b%7]) with mapi id 15.20.2707.030; Wed, 12 Feb 2020
 11:27:30 +0000
Sender: facturacion.electronica@test.com
From: "facturacion.electronica@test.com"
 <facturacion.electronica@test.com>
To: recepcion_fe@test.com.co
Date: 12 Feb 2020 06:27:30 -0500
Subject: =?utf-8?B?RkFDVFVSQSBERSBWRU5UQSBOQUNJT05BTCAwMDEtUkVGLTAx?=
 =?utf-8?B?LVJFRjcxMDYyICBQcm9kdWNjacOzbiBIb3RlbCBEYW5uIENhcnRhZ2Vu?=
 =?utf-8?B?YQ==?=
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary=--boundary_12346_eba0a556-46b2-45ae-a83c-6a328945cc15
X-ClientProxiedBy: MN2PR15CA0066.namprd15.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:10b6:208:237::35) To SN6PR01MB4190.prod.exchangelabs.com
 (2603:10b6:805:ad::32)
Return-Path: facturacion.electronica@test.com
Message-ID:
 <SN6PR01MB4190EA7816CC103D037F6292EC1B0@SN6PR01MB4190.prod.exchangelabs.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from W1BOGFE01 (190.131.255.156) by MN2PR15CA0066.namprd15.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:208:237::35) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384) id 15.20.2707.21 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 12 Feb 2020 11:27:29 +0000
X-Originating-IP: [190.131.255.156]
X-MS-PublicTrafficType: Email
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 10d0e98f-a121-421b-9c11-08d7afae8be9
X-MS-TrafficTypeDiagnostic: SN6PR01MB4063:
X-Microsoft-Antispam-PRVS:
    <SN6PR01MB406322F7D74C242982CD1B5CEC1B0@SN6PR01MB4063.prod.exchangelabs.com>
X-MS-Oob-TLC-OOBClassifiers: OLM:83;
X-Forefront-PRVS: 0311124FA9
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
    SFV:NSPM;SFS:(10009020)(396003)(376002)(346002)(366004)(136003)(39850400004)(199004)(189003)(2906002)(7846003)(21460400002)(26005)(15974865002)(6486002)(52536014)(66576008)(235185007)(8936002)(33656002)(66476007)(478600001)(9686003)(66556008)(66946007)(5660300002)(6666004)(81156014)(86362001)(224303003)(16526019)(316002)(186003)(52116002)(6916009)(956004)(33964004)(6496006)(81166006);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;SCL:1;SRVR:SN6PR01MB4063;H:SN6PR01MB4190.prod.exchangelabs.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:es;PTR:InfoNoRecords;A:1;MX:1;
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: test.com does not designate
 permitted sender hosts)
X-MS-Exchange-SenderADCheck: 1
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info:
    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
X-MS-Exchange-AntiSpam-MessageData:
    2eIX7CdiRcVZUk0awA2EA1yJsOZkal1Er4TiHdWU2bYLBXEWVLO/l9oIauHINZYE6p5ap5qgFBE6EaPaIrzaqwX4ddDUCneycz//MRRfbnwZPlCacW93r3+QvYRF/UqMytkJVL1EBfYydwamT16CkA==
X-OriginatorOrg: test.com
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 10d0e98f-a121-421b-9c11-08d7afae8be9
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Feb 2020 11:27:30.8254
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Hosted
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: a39cadfb-0558-4e74-b517-dcb26da274ce
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-MailboxType: HOSTED
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-UserPrincipalName: FyHsQ7dJ88P/rpbSbIoOrTZDGBTHZMAbjcCNPDok87AvtOV/5Y2ADMsxKP7+OaMhwSuHb87oE1sO04zsc1bs99ZGxaMWtGCJlAQb6tOlAy5oVrCwTp+fbTFOI/JBjrw1
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: SN6PR01MB4063
```

there is the .mime file that have the all informaction.

Another way to read file name of the attachment ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not all attachments have file names.  If you provide more details, such as the MIME content of a message that has problems, perhaps I can help.

Comment: Hello Bill, thank you soo much!! The .mime file has two attachments.

Comment: Hello Bill, thank you soo much!! The .mime file has two attachments.  Example: `MimeMultipart : multipart/mixed  , bodyPart.getContentType() : multipart/alternative; boundary=--boundary_12345_741ee73a-db6e-4434-ba5f-8460ae5bf37f .   bodyPart.getContent() : javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@56c6e536 ` .....The big problem is that i can not get the filename from the bodyPart , I have to save the filename of the attachments in my database and after extract the extension filename, in that case i do not know how i should get that property. bodyPart.getFileName() returns null.

Comment: I need to see the full MIME structure of the message.  You can excise any sensitive information.   Update your original post and add it.

Comment: Hello Bill, The full MIME structure  has been udpated, thank you.

Comment: You only added the message headers, I also need to see the entire message body that includes all the headers for each body part.